# Using two python environments in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, lint

Is it possible to have two python environments simultaneously "activated" within vscode? One environment would be the project's env (say, in a local folder venv), and the other environment being the global environment that has the linters and general formatting packages.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, why not just have the projects env linked to global, so global doesn't have dupes and it automatically updates the global list.

A symbolic link or a hard link should work.